# «au maximum», «au minimum»: locutions adverbiales

Tags: usage, néologismes, locutions

Quand je consulte mes dictionnaires en papier ou le TLFi, je remarque que les mots *maximum* et *minimum* sont des noms ou à la limite des adjectifs, acception indiquée comme critiquée chez Larousse, et la plupart des sources renvoient à *maximal/minimal*, sans doute les juge-t-on plus recommendables.

Il me semble cependant que les locutions adverbiales *au maximum* et *au minimum* (*autant que possible* / *aussi peu que possible*) sont apparues depuis au moins quelques décennies et sont bien vivantes, car j'entends régulièrement l'expression **réduire au maximum**, qui ne saurait s'interpréter aussi littéralement qu'une descente vers la limite supérieure (le maximum), naturelle si on limite la définition de *maximum* à un nom.

S'il ne s'agissait aussi que des gens qui m'entourent, gens ayant peu d'intérêt dans l'étude approfondie des subtilités de la grammaire, on pourrait penser qu'il s'agit d'un phénomène populaire de peu d'importance. Mais il ne s'agit pas que d'eux: de la bouche de professeurs, de politiciens, d’activistes, de gens qui savent parler en public sans bafouiller, à la radio sans se répéter, qui peuvent exprimer une idée complexe sans hésiter, j'entends souvent cette expression, qui semble selon Ngram avoir pris son envol dans les années ’40 et ’50 et s'être taillé une place au soleil au détriment de **réduire au minimum** (qui domine encore, mais qui a pris du plomb dans l'aile).

[image]

Ainsi, quand la Commission de la santé et de la sécurité au travail (CSST, organisme gouvernemental québécois) indique qu'il faut *«réduire au maximum toutes les ouvertures»* lors de la conception d'une enceinte insonorisante, je doute que l'on fasse allusion au fait qu'il faille passer de trop à juste assez pour ne pas trop en avoir.

[image]

Quand MSN propose des trucs pour [réduire au maximum les déchets de sa cuisine](https://www.msn.com/fr-ca/cuisine-et-vins/actualites-alimentaires/les-5-r%C3%A8gles-dor-pour-r%C3%A9duire-au-maximum-les-d%C3%A9chets-dans-sa-cuisine/ar-BBwKSGI), ils ne s'adressent pas qu'à ceux qui gaspillent trop trop trop et aimeraient atteindre le maximum tolérable de production de déchets, mais à tous ceux qui souhaitent réduire autant que faire se peut leurs déchets.

Lorsque le Regroupement des jeunes courtiers du Québec propose une formation qui permettra aux conseillers de [réduire au maximum les impôts de leurs clients](http://rjcq.org/evenements/2016-02-05/), ils ne veulent certes pas faire payer le maximum à des clients consentants: ils savent que ce genre de clientèle est rare et que miser sur son existence est un pari perdu d'avance.

Il me semble donc clair qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un épiphénomène.

- Existe-t-il des études, des références sérieuses et des discussions (pas des dénonciations unilatérales svp) sur cette relative nouveauté linguistique?
- Est-elle pressentie comme présente pour demeurer?

Comment: Je ne suis pas choqué par « réduire au maximum » qui est quasiment toujours synonyme de « réduire le plus possible ». La raison étant que l'on ne peut en général pas partir de plus haut que le maximum. En revanche, « réduire au minimum » peut être ambigu, le contexte permettant de savoir ce qui doit être minimal, la réduction ou l'objectif à atteindre. Il y a aussi le cas « réduire au maximum autorisé » ou la réduction n'est ni maximale, ni minimale mais précisément ciblée.

Comment: Ça ne me choque pas non plus. Je suis seulement très surpris du silence absolu gardé sur cet usage par les références linguistiques habituelles. Je crois que la réduction au maximum autorisé (contaminants dans un produit, par exemple) est bien la signification que l'on pourrait déduire avec un dictionnaire, mais dans la plupart des cas, ce n'est pas celle que l'on déduirait du contexte en utilisant notre entendement.

Comment: Relative nouveauté linguistique? Ou nouveauté linguistique plutôt neuve? Je ne vois pas le problème. En français metropolitain on voit réduire au maximum partout. Que diriez-vous à la place de cette expression?

Comment: C'est une nouveauté relative: ça ne date ni du moyen-âge, ni même de Victor Hugo. C'est plus vieux que moi, mais pas que mes grands-parents. Dans l'histoire du français, c'est d'hier. Mon opinion ici ne compte pas, mais je l'ai déjà mentionnée: ça ne me choque pas. J'alterne entre _réduire au maximum_ et _réduire autant que possible_, le second plus souvent à cause de l'absence d'ambiguïté que je cherche parfois, mais je ne me considère pas une référence linguistique à l'oral: ma langue a bien des défauts, certains volontaires, d'autres, la plupart sûrement, involontaires.

Comment: @Feelew - l'expression me semble effectivement moderne, et en fait peut-être même d'un style non recommandé en litérature. Peut-être l'expression "réduire le plus possible" serait-elle classiquement plus acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La position médiane entre verbe et complément autorise une association à gauche avec le verbe ou une association à droite avec le complément.
C'est donc bien l'usage courant qui permet de choisir son camp :

'**réduire au maximum** *(quoi?)* les déchets de la cuisine'  : usage courant; compréhension correcte.
'réduire *(quoi?)* **au maximum les déchets** de la cuisine' :  français correct, mais non sens !

S'il n'y a pas de non sens possible comme avec:
' réduire **au minimum** les déchets de la cuisine',
il reste un choix possible sur :
' **réduire au minimum** (c'est à dire réduire à peine) les déchets'
ou
'réduire **au minimum les déchets**'.

Comme l'usage courant d'aujourd'hui privilégie le verbe, on préférera lever le doute avec un possessif explicite :
"réduire **à leur** minimum  **les déchets** de la cuisine".

J'imagine que ce sont ces deux formes, association d'usage avec le verbe et sinon, possessif explicite, qui demeureront ... jusqu'au prochain usage courant...

Comment: Merci! J'aime votre analyse et votre ouverture à des horizons différents que ceux balisés. En écrivant ma question, je pensais beaucoup à des scientifiques mesurant un signal discret et délicat dans les années '30 ou '40, et affirmant qu'il serait convenable de « réduire au minimum le bruit de fond ». Ce genre de message eut été parfaitement clair dans les circonstances. Cibler quelque chose « au minimum » aujourd'hui, dans ce monde très compétitif à tous les niveaux (y compris linguistique) qui est le nôtre, passerait probablement moins bien dès son élocution.